# CGMakePoint(X,Y) for a image

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone development. can any one let me know what is `CGMakePoint(x,y)` and what x, y stands for and how to get CGPoint x and y value for a image.?

Comment: Question body is *commented out*, so there is no question at all? :-)

Answer (score 3):

CGMakePoint is a function that returns a CGPoint structure initialized with the given coordinates.

Not sure what you mean by the "CGPoint x and y value for a image".  The position of a UIImage in a view?  You use image.frame to get the rectangle (CGRect) of the images's position within the parent view, and image.frame.origin to get the top/right coordinate.